# Capturing h.264 stream from camera with Gstreamer

Tags: h.264, gstreamer, v4l2

I'm trying to capture H264 stream from locally installed Logitech C920 camera from `/dev/video0` with `Gstreamer 1.0` `v4l2src` element.

`v4l2-ctl --list-formats` shows that camera is capable to give H264 video format:

```
# v4l2-ctl --list-formats
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        ...

        Index       : 1
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'H264' (compressed)
        Name        : H.264

        ...
```

But pipeline

`# gst-launch-1.0 -vvv v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-h264, width=800, height=448, framerate=30/1 ! fakesink`

keeps giving me `not-negotiated (-4)` error:

```
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)800, height=(int)448, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)800, height=(int)448, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFakeSink:fakesink0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)800, height=(int)448, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)800, height=(int)448, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2809): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 67687169 ns.
```

Any help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is gstreamer mandatory for your needs? I also have lots of problems with the Logitech C920 in H264 mode and gstreamer. But I managed to use VLC as a RTSP server to use the C920 with H264:

```
$ cvlc -v v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma="H264":width=1024:height=570:fps=30 \
       --sout="#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/live}"
```

Then I can connect with another VLC to the URI rtsp://localhost:8554/live

If GStreamer is mandatory for you, I only managed to use it with a capture utility that you can find here: https://github.com/csete/bonecam - directory "capture"

You have to compile it, but if you have some programming skills it shoud be very easy as there is only one C file and a script to help. Just pass "host" as a parameter to the script :

```
# Get the bonecam/capture content or git clone the directory, and then
$ cd bonecam/capture
$ ./build host
```

You can use the "capture" utility with something like that :

```
$ v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-fmt-video=width=1024,height=570,pixelformat=1
$ v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-parm=30
$ ./bonecam/capture/capture -d /dev/video0 -c 100000 -o | \
      gst-launch -e filesrc location=/dev/fd/0 ! legacyh264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=10.0.0.42 port=5000
```

If you do not like to specify the number of frame to get ("-c" parameter with "capture"), there is a fork to this utility that you can find here: https://github.com/DeLaGuardo/bonecam

I know there is a plugin categorized as "bad", called uvch264 for gstreamer 0.10, that should work with the C920. But I do not know for gstreamer 1.0, and I could not test it.

**UPD:**

Don't forget to add `--rtsp-timeout=-1` to `cvlc` command line like

```
$ cvlc -v v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma="H264":width=1024:height=570:fps=30 \
       --sout="#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/live}" --rtsp-timeout=-1
```

Without this option streaming only lasts for 60 seconds by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `cvlc` works like a charm! I'm using it on Rasperry Pi.

Comment: With the C920 being in H264 mode? Are you sure? I had lots of problems enabling the H264 mode of the camera with the Raspberry Pi, due to USB problems on the Raspberry Pi. Some H264 frames are lost because of that problem, so the video is weird. Actually, because of that, I am using the C920 on a Beaglebone.
Anyway, if it works for you I suppose there was an update in the firmware to solve this problem.

Comment: I had such USB problem with dropping frames before. I've installed new Rapbian kernel as desbribed here (https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/238). Drop frame problem disappeared. Now streaming H264 video is very smooth.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will redo my tests with this update.

Answer (score 4):

I have been trying to do the same thing and I got the same error. I believe I was using GStreamer 1.0.6.

What I found, possibly even thanks to Fergal Butler's answer, was the following page:

http://kakaroto.homelinux.net/2012/09/uvc-h264-encoding-cameras-support-in-gstreamer/

Here Youness Alaoui describes the uvch264_src element he made to bring H264 camera support to GStreamer.

He describes the port to GStreamer 1.0 as pending in his article. So over the last week I've been looking into this. It turns out that it *has* now been ported to GStreamer 1.0, but only in a developer release (Version 1.1.2).

You can get version 1.1.2 here:

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/

It's called "uvch264src" now, and it's a part of gst-plugins-bad. I think it is also present in version 1.1.1 but I haven't really looked into that.

I had a bit of a hard time getting it installed, I think mostly due to to conflicts with GST 1.0 packages installed on my PC (so my own fault). But note that it has dependencies on libgudev-1.0-dev and libusb-1.0-0-dev so install these packages first - it took me a while to work out it was those two I was missing.

Here is a pipeline I got to work which uses uvch264:

`gst-launch-1.0 uvch264src device=/dev/video0 name=src auto-start=true src.vfsrc ! video/x-raw, format=YUY2, width=160, height=90, framerate=5/1 ! xvimagesink  src.vidsrc ! queue ! video/x-h264, width=800, height=448, framerate=30/1 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! xvimagesink`

If you don't want to use the preview video (from the vfsrc pad) just hook src.vfsrc straight up to a fakesink. I should also mention that even though this pipeline is working for me, I get a lot of warnings about "Got data flow before segment event". So obviously I'm not doing something right, but I'm not sure what.

Anyway, after all of that messing about getting 1.1.2 and uvch264src completely installed and working, I decided to give v4l2src a quick go again. And it turns out that v4l2src supports H264 properly after all :/. (See the short answer.)

---

## Short Answer:

So the short answer to your question is that if you are happy to install 1.1.2 from source you'll be able to do exactly what you want in the same way you've been trying to do it. You shouldn't need uvch264src. I've tested your pipeline and it worked fine with my installation. I've also tried this simple pipeline, to display the video on-screen, and it worked fine for me as well:

`gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-h264, width=800, height=448, framerate=30/1 ! avdec_h264 ! xvimagesink sync=false`

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe v4l2src supports h264 at the moment.  See here:

http://www.oz9aec.net/index.php/gstreamer/473-using-the-logitech-c920-webcam-with-gstreamer

and here:

http://kakaroto.homelinux.net/2012/09/uvc-h264-encoding-cameras-support-in-gstreamer/

Comment: Just imagine if these link breaks one day. So please explain the links you have quoted

Comment: h264 is now supported by v4l2src

Answer (score 1):

Try use videoconvert for automatically convert the video to a format understood by the video sink

```
gst-launch-1.0 -vvv v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I've also got a Logitech C920 camera, and have used the following pipeline to record H.264 video from the camera:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-h264,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 ! mpegtsmux ! filesink location=output.ts
```

This asks the camera to produce H.264 data, which I then mux into a [MPEG transport stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream) container, and write to disk.  I can play the resulting file successfully with Totem.

The above pipeline records at 720p.  The camera can also record at 1080p if you change the requested format to `width=1920,height=1080`.